# TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined in setInterval

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so I have this problem right here. I'm making like an updating state about the bot's connection and things, but there is an error when I specify the channel and message. Here is the error:

```
let msg = chn.messages.fetch("862718466803761163")
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
```

I have checked so many times, even my friend said there is nothing wrong. Well, here is the code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
    let chn = client.channels.cache.get(c => c.id === "862704580423581718")
    let msg = chn.messages.fetch("862718466803761163")
    let state
    let ping = client.ws.ping
    if (ping < 200) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_excellent:855856200078589982>'
      state = "Volta's connection is excellent."
    }
    if (ping < 600) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_good:873563598973177876>'
      state = "Volta's connection is a bit slow."
    }
    if (ping < 1000) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_bad:873563598977388554>'
      state = "Volta's connection is stable."
    }
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#3EDD1B')
      .setTitle('-- Actual State --')
      .setDescription(`${emoji} [${ping}ms]: ${state}\n\n`
      + `<a:loading:855847974521536512> It updates every **5 minutes**.`)
      .setFooter(`:zap: Uptime: ${prettyMs(client.uptime)}`)
    msg.edit(embed)
  }, checkthe_interval)
```

*Yes, it is in a setInterval. Yes, it is in the event ready. No, it's not a module.exports, it's in the main file.*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you define `chn` you're actually changing the `c.id` to `862704580423581718` instead of looking for it. That'll return an empty object. Also the function for fetching messages is `<channel>.messages.fetch(...)`.

Full example:

```js
setInterval(async function() { // Start the interval
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js'); // Define MessageEmbed
    let chn = client.channels.cache.get(c => c.id == "862704580423581718"); // Find a channel in the cache
    let msg = await chn.messages.fetch("862718466803761163"); // Fetch the message from an ID
    let state;
    let ping = client.ws.ping;
    if (ping < 200) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_excellent:855856200078589982>';
      state = "Volta's connection is excellent.";
    }
    if (ping < 600) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_good:873563598973177876>';
      state = "Volta's connection is a bit slow.";
    }
    if (ping < 1000) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_bad:873563598977388554>';
      state = "Volta's connection is stable.";
    }
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#3EDD1B')
      .setTitle('-- Actual State --')
      .setDescription(`${emoji} [${ping}ms]: ${state}\n\n`
      + `<a:loading:855847974521536512> It updates every **5 minutes**.`)
      .setFooter(`:zap: Uptime: ${prettyMs(client.uptime)}`)
    msg.edit(embed)
}, checkthe_interval)
```

Comment: Erm, I just tested. This still doesn't work.

Comment: @CrossTR15_YT Are you getting any errors?

Comment: nvm, I already got it working. Btw, doing like your example and it was still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is solved. I didn't need the `(c => c.id === "862704580423581718");`
Here is the solved code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
    let chn = client.channels.cache.get("862704580423581718")
    let msg = chn.messages.fetch("862718466803761163")
    let state
    let ping = client.ws.ping
    if (ping < 200) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_excellent:855856200078589982>'
      state = "Volta's connection is excellent."
    }
    if (ping < 600) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_good:873563598973177876>'
      state = "Volta's connection is a bit slow."
    }
    if (ping < 1000) {
      emoji = '<:the_connection_is_bad:873563598977388554>'
      state = "Volta's connection is stable."
    }
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#3EDD1B')
      .setTitle('-- Actual State --')
      .setDescription(`${emoji} [${ping}ms]: ${state}\n\n`
      + `<a:loading:855847974521536512> It updates every **5 minutes**.`)
      .setFooter(`:zap: Uptime: ${prettyMs(client.uptime)}`)
    msg.edit(embed)
  }, checkthe_interval)
```